# Can't enable/disable plugins in non bulk mode

Tags: plugins

I've WordPress (4.5.3) setup and for some reason it lost ability to disable / enable plugins in other way then thru Bulk Actions. I am not sure when exactly this happened and why? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough it was one plugin **Buooy Aviary Editor** (which on screenshot gives option to Deactivate). After deactivating everything is back.